# C# - Straight-up answer for using Regex to compare strings?

Tags: c#, regex, string-comparison

I cannot understand the syntax at all! I feel like the stackoverflow community should get a simple solution to the problem I have (hopefully I'm not blind and have missed one of the thousands of regex questions here):

```
string myString = "$randomText$";
string myString2 = "$otherStuff$";
```

What would I use to check if any string has "$*$"? So as long as there's 2 $'s on the outside of the text?

Again, I'm sorry, and I Do understand there's other regex answers out there, but there's no way I'll ever understand it. I apologize, and have a good day.

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you need to compare? The 2 strings here are different. Do you just want to check if the string has `$` at both ends? Then why regex?

Comment: You need to capture the whole word with `$`s or just whats between them?

Comment: I'm trying to compare to see if any two strings have $ at the beginning and the end.

Comment: $ is a regex control character, meaning end of string. Escape it with backslash. string myString = "\$randomText\$";

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by using this:

```
string myString = "$randomText$";
var match = Regex.Match(myString , @"\$.+\$");
```

Comment: This is Exactly what I needed, thanks. Thank you everyone else who tried to answer.

Comment: this should check for `match.Success` for a boolean result as to whether the string contains `$.*$`. Though this would also match (perhaps wrongly): `asdf$12345$asdf` where `$` is not on the outside of the text

Answer (score 3):

You have two options. Use regex or don't. You could either substr the input string and check the first and last char are the `$` sign, or you could use regex. If you're new and don't understand regex (learn to love it, a little goes a long way) then go with the substring checks. You may also find that substringing is slightly faster than regex.

For those that want spoonfeeding (untested code). This will be (most likely) be faster than any regex check:

```
public bool DollahCheck(string inp, string stringToCheck = "$")
{
    return inp.Substring(0,1) == stringToCheck && inp.Substring(inp.Length - 1) == stringToCheck;
}
```

Comment: This ain't C# solution, still it's true.

Answer (score 0):

use this
bool matched =  Regex.Match(myString , @"yourRegexPattern").Success